# How to deal with numeric instability in stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: regularization, stochastic-gradient-descent

Imagine that we try to perform sgd using a gradient that takes very small or very large values (e.g. it is a product of many terms that are larger than 1). Is there a standard approach to deal with the numeric instability issues that will arise when implementing the algorithm on a computer?

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach uses a [preconditioner](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner) to normalize the feature variables.

Here's a [related discussion on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156226/andrew-ng-scaling-and-normalizing-expression) and a [better explanation than I could give, courtesy of Andrew Ng](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/machine-learning/gradient-descent-in-practice-i-feature-scaling-xx3Da)

Comment: Does it mean that scaling or standardization of feature variables reduce the numerical instability?

Comment: Yes, the instability is due to extreme curvature of the error surface, which is dramatically reduced by the normalization.

Comment: The "very small or very large" is a textbook case of "poorly conditioned problem" and you are right, the way to engage poor condition is by improving the conditioning.  There are also optimizers that have a damping term in the gradient that substantially decrease the learning rate for high jumps in the size of the gradient step.  There are kinds of losses that also clamp the maximum value of the gradient that is back-propagated in the learning step.  This could depend if small means close to zero or close to negative infinity.  Some folks look at log-transforming the way the error is handled.